# ADB to Toggle Adaptive brightness button

Tags: android, adb, toggle, screen-brightness

Am running a ADB on android to check the toggle of Adaptive brightness inside display settings. I tried using `adb shell settings put system screen_brightness_mode 0`. This works, but the button didn't get toggled(enable/disabled) on the UI. I want to directly call the button via adb to make the toggle, but not via injecting touch based on a coordinate. Someone can help me on this please.
For example Like this: `adb shell am start -a android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE`

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such event. You can do some hack to update the UI like If you are in the settings screen, simulate back button and again start settings screen.

Comment: Yes.. After enabling it via adb am going back and then returning to the same page.  then only its updating. Is this functionality is by default ?

Comment: Yes. This is the default behavior. When you change brightness mode using adb, there is no way to tell the UI to update its state.